# How to make excerpt filter in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-filters

i'm new to angular 2 , i used to get the excerpt of a text in angularjs with a filter like this :

**app.filters.js:**

```
app.filter('excerpt', function () {
    return function (text, length) {
        if (text.length > length) {
            return text.substr(0, length) + '...';
        }
        return text;
    }
});
```

**in html file :**

```
{{blog.content | excerpt:90}}
```

what's the equivalent in angular 2 ?

Comment: Pipes: https://angular.io/guide/pipes. Note that the docs provide an AngularJS:Angular mapping for you: https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be doing it :

- First create your filter `.ts` file :

**excerpt.filter.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'excerpt',
  pure: false
})
export class ExcerptFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: String, length:any ): any {
    if (!text || !length) {
      return text;
    }
    if (text.length > length) {
      return text.substr(0, length) + '...';
    }
      return text;

  }
}
```

- Then you can use it like the following :

**template.component.html**

```
<div class="description">{{blog.content | excerpt:90}} </div>
```

- Make sure that you're importing your filter in `app.module.ts` file :

  `import {ExcerptFilter} from './filters/excerpt.filter';`

for more infos about creating pipes see [the Docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'excerpt'
})
export class ExcerptPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string, length: number): string {
    if (text.length > length) {
      return text.substr(0, length) + '...';
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

`{{ textToTransform | excerpt: 90 }}`

Remember to add the pipe in your module.